# Working on a program for buying tickets to a movie. Trying to figure out if I maybe need a while loop for what im trying to accomplish?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a program for movie tickets. The program has to compute the price of a theater ticket. The program should prompt the user for the patron's age and whether the movie is 3D. Children and seniors should receive a discounted price. There should be a surcharge for movies that are 3D. The program should output the ticket price for the movie ticket based on the age entered and whether the movie is in 3D. I have got half the program to work. Children and seniors get discounted prices.

I have almost completed the program but when I ask if the movie is 3D or not it prints out the same for Yes and No responses. When the user types "No" I want to make it say the price of the ticket stays the same. And, when they type "Yes" it needs to show the new price of the ticket for 3D. It already does the correct thing when typing "Yes" but the problem is it says the same output when typing "No" Not sure if I need to store yes and no in another variable or maybe a while loop? Could anyone point me in the right direction please? Any help is appreciated.

```
age = int(input("Welcome to the movie theatre. What is your age? Children and senior citizens will receive a discount.   "))

children_ticket = 8

adult_ticket = 10

senior_ticket = 8

if age <= 12:
    print("The children's ticket costs"  ,children_ticket)
    
if age >= 65:
    print("The senior citizens ticket costs" ,senior_ticket)

if (age >= 13) and (age <= 64):
    print("The adult ticket costs" ,adult_ticket)


three_d = input("Is the movie you're watching 3D? If so, they have a surcharge.  ")

three_d_surcharge = 2

if age <= 12:
    print("The children's ticket for 3D costs"  ,children_ticket + three_d_surcharge)
    
if age >= 65:
    print("The senior citizens ticket for 3D costs" ,senior_ticket + three_d_surcharge)

if (age >= 13) and (age <= 64):
    print("The adult ticket for 3D costs" ,adult_ticket + three_d_surcharge)
```

[3D movie ticket results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83FyT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the result of three_d in a if statement, the .lower() allows for a wider input range should the user enter `Yes` for example

```py
age = int(input("Welcome to the movie theatre. What is your age? Children and senior citizens will receive a discount.   "))

children_ticket = 8

adult_ticket = 10

senior_ticket = 8

if age <= 12:
    print("The children's ticket costs", children_ticket)

if age >= 65:
    print("The senior citizens ticket costs", senior_ticket)

if (age >= 13) and (age <= 64):
    print("The adult ticket costs", adult_ticket)

three_d = input("Is the movie you're watching 3D? If so, they have a surcharge.  ")

three_d_surcharge = 2

if three_d.lower() == "yes":
    if age >= 65:
        print("The senior citizens ticket for 3D costs", senior_ticket + three_d_surcharge)
    elif age > 12:
        print("The adult ticket for 3D costs", adult_ticket + three_d_surcharge)
    else:
        print("The children's ticket for 3D costs", children_ticket + three_d_surcharge)
else:
    print("No 3d surcharge")
```

You can also change the way the if checks work so that there are less checks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do an if else statement for the `three_d` variable. Something like

```
if three_d=='yes':
    ...
else:
    print("the price of the ticket stays the same")
```